# Why is this call to strstr not returning false?

Tags: php, string, casting, strstr

I've stumbled upon an issue with [strstr](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) in an old legacy codebase. There's lot of code, but basically the test case would come down to this:

```
$value = 2660;
$link = 'affiliateid=1449&zoneid=6011&placement_id=11736&publisher_id=1449&period_preset=yesterday&period_start=2017-03-27&period_end=2017-03-27';

var_dump(strstr($link, $value));
```

I would expect this to return `false` since "2660" is not in the string however it returns `d=1449&zoneid=6011&placement_id=11736&publisher_id=1449&period_preset=yesterday&period_start=2017-03-27&period_end=2017-03-27`.

I realise that `$value` should be a string but still I don't understand why it's not casted to a string by PHP and why it's finding this number in the link.

Actually, if I try with `$value = '2660';` it returns `false` as expected.

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Just stringify it `var_dump(strstr($link, (string)$value));` PHP is not a strict language and tends to give strange results, when different types are being compared. Just like `(1=="a1")` equals as true.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but... what "strstr" means? I checked the documentation and I honestly don't have a clue why such a weird name was picked up for this function! Is it "Stray String"? "Search This Range for a String"? "String String"?

Comment: @Tsar, yeah it's neither a good name nor a good function. Maybe it comes from strpos which returns the **pos**ition of the first occurrence, while strstr returns the **str**ing at the first occurrence.

Comment: @TSar: `strstr` finds a **str**ing inside another **str**ing.  Don't blame PHP for this; the name comes from C.

Comment: @jwodder Eh, that's not an excuse :P But fair point. C is know to be really... uh, let's say, _exotic_ regarding some naming decisions here and there, so I'm not surprised at all!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### Short answer

When you run `strstr($str, 2660)` the `$needle` is resolved to the character *"**d**"* by calling `chr(2660)` and therefore it stops at the first *"**d**"* found in the given `$str`, in this case right at the 11th character.

---

#### Why are we calling `chr(2660)`?

Because when the `$needle` is not a string [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) casts that argument to an integer and uses the corresponding character for that position from the [extended ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) where `chr(2660)` is *"**d**"*.

> *If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and applied as the ordinal value of a character.*

---

#### But why does `chr(2660)` return *"**d**"* when *"**d**"* is `ord(100)`?

Because values outside the valid range `[0-255]` will be bitwise and'ed with `255`, which is equivalent to the following algorithm<sup>[[source]](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)</sup>

```
while ($ascii < 0) {
    $ascii += 256;
}
$ascii %= 256;
```

So, `2660` becomes `100`, and then when passed to [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) it's used as the ordinal value of the character and looks for character *"**d**"*.

Confusing? **Yes**. I also expected it to be casted to a string, but that's what we get for assuming things in programming. This, at least, is documented; you'd be surprised the amount of times something *weird* happens and there's no official explanation to be found. At least not as easily as following the same link you provided.

---

#### Why is it named `strstr`?

I did a little bit of research and found [this gem](https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/rat/d11.html) (Rationale for 
American National Standard 
      for Information Systems -
      Programming Language -
C) from all the way back 1989 where they named all the functions relating to strings with the prefix `str` which is logical, then since PHP's source is written in C it will explain why it has carried. My best guess is that we are searching for a **str**ing inside another **str**ing, they do say:

> *The strstr function is an invention of the Committee.  It is included
>   as a hook for efficient substring algorithms, or for built-in
>   substring instructions.*

### Useful docs

- Documentation for [`strstr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)
- Documentation for [`chr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)
- [PHPwtf](http://www.phpwtf.org/) a good resource for weirdness

---

Comment: I looked into [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php), apparently it checks division with 256 `$ascii %= 256;`, thus 2660 turns into 100 which is `d`. That is actually pretty strange creation.

Comment: Yeah, it is kind-of documented in the PHP doc, [*"Example #2 Overflow behavior"*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php). Also, the first comment there truly sheds light on it: *"Note that if the number is higher than 256, it will return the number mod 256."*. Weird that this isn't noted more clearly in the *Return Values* or *Parameters* section though.

Comment: Well, PHP usually comes with a large set of confusing _weird_ things

Answer (score 8):

I think this answers your question:

> needle 
>   If needle is not a string, it is converted to an integer and
>   applied as the ordinal value of a character.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php

Edit because of the comments:

`chr(2660)` returns character `d`, which is indeed in the haystack and that's why it won't return false as you expected.

Comment: ,,,so 2660 is which character?! :)

Comment: Which... is not in the haystack.

Comment: Yes I googled "spade" but @Juan Cortés with a (slightly cheeky) later answer says char(2660) is a d. Interesting

Comment: Hm, `ord("♠")` gives `226`, `chr(2660)` gives `d`!

Comment: @domdom, precisely, that's what I was just writing as a response. And `d` is indeed in the haystack.